# Emacs loops mysteriously

Tags: iteration

I am using emacs 25.3 and I observe that one indentation function that I wrote loop mysteriously. My function goes following:

```
(defun aut-indent-func ()
  (interactive)

  (defun loop (begin)
    (goto-char begin)
    (let* ((end (line-end-position 1))
           (substr (buffer-substring-no-properties begin end)))
      (if (string-match-p (regexp-quote "=") substr)
          ; then we are in a definition line
          (let ((field (string-trim
                        (substring-no-properties
                         substr
                         0
                         (string-match (regexp-quote "=") substr)))))
            (string-equal field "transitions"))
        ; then we need to call recursively
        (if (/= begin (line-beginning-position 0))
            (loop (line-beginning-position 0))))))

  (if (save-excursion
        (loop (line-beginning-position 0)))
      (progn
        (indent-to-left-margin)
        (back-to-indentation)
        (indent-to-column (+ 2 (aut-eq-line-offset))))
    (indent-relative)))
```

Essentially, it tries to loop over each line and try to identify a lines comes with `transitions =` and put the indentation at the same column as the equal sign there.

However, this functions loops.

It's impossible, since it keep scanning up and stop when it hits the top. What's even more mysterious is, if I evaluate the function definition again, it stops looping, until the next time I open up emacs again(and the file containing this function got reloaded). So I do `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`, and it shows following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  (while t (line-beginning-position 0))
  (save-excursion (while t (line-beginning-position 0)))
  (if (save-excursion (while t (line-beginning-position 0))) (progn (indent-to-left-margin) (back-to-indentation) (indent-to-column (+ 2 (aut-eq-line-offset)))) (indent-relative))
  aut-indent-func()
  indent-according-to-mode()
  electric-indent-post-self-insert-function()
  self-insert-command(1)
  newline(nil 1)
  funcall-interactively(newline nil 1)
  call-interactively(newline nil nil)
  command-execute(newline)
```

well, this trace shows something seriously insane. As you can tell from the code, there isn't `(while t ...)`, so who adds those? Is it a bug that emacs add `while` automatically in some occasion?

Comment: `loop` already exists in Emacs. Maybe you call the `loop` which is an alias to `cl-loop` when you think you call your `loop`?

Comment: @choroba but that doesn't explain `while t` does it? let me try to rename `loop` to a different name.

Comment: @choroba wow, actually you are right. hmm, that's really curious.

Comment: Don't nest function definitions, they don't define internal functions. Elisp ain't Scheme.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Not curious at all, `loop`/`cl-loop` is a well-known macro which expands to `(while t ...)` in this case. See [`(cl) Loop Facility`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Loop-Facility.html). The only curiosity is that one of the packages you are using has loaded the deprecated `cl` feature instead of `cl-lib` at runtime.

Comment: @wasamasa what idiom would you suggest on writing helper recursion?

Comment: Write a named function. And don't use recursion instead of iteration, Elisp ain't Scheme. When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

Comment: Use `cl-labels` to define and use a lexically-scoped named helper function which you can call recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the infinite loop is due to an identification of the call to `(loop ...)` as referring to the [`loop`/`cl-loop`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Loop-Facility.html) macro from Emacs' [Common Lisp emulation library](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/) and its subsequent macroexpansion to an Elisp [`(while t ...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Iteration.html) loop.

I believe you can make your code simpler, more idiomatic and a good deal faster whilst avoiding the other issues mentioned in the comments by writing something like:

```el
(defun aut-search-definition-backward ()
  "Return non-nil if current line is preceded by a definition."
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (re-search-backward (rx bow "transitions" (* space) ?=) nil t)))

(defun aut-indent ()
  "Forever indentured."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (aut-search-definition-backward))
      (indent-relative)
    (indent-to-left-margin)
    (back-to-indentation)
    (indent-to-column (+ 2 (aut-eq-line-offset)))))
```

The regexp used is intended for illustration; you should, of course, modify it for your needs/preferences.

Here are some relevant tips for the future:

- Prefer buffer over string operations where reasonable, as the former are much more optimised than the latter. Emacs provides a plethora of relevant functionality; see [`(elisp) Searching and Matching`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-and-Matching.html).
- Avoid recursion where iteration is reasonable, lest you go too far down the rabbit hole and hit rock bottom. In addition, function calls are still not terribly efficient in Elisp.
- Avoid definitions such as `defvar`, `defun` etc. anywhere other than the top-level of your file, otherwise the reader/byte-compiler may not "see" them, as "seen" here. :)

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as avoiding all recursion (processing trees iteratively is rather confusing), but would steer clear of all cases where iteration is the goal.

Comment: @wasamasa I never meant to imply never, rather that Elisp is not well-suited for recursion. Is my new wording better or should I dial it down even further?

Comment: Yeah, it's better now.

Comment: yeah I will look more into elisp's APIs.